# Integral from inverse Fouriertransform of 1/(1+p^2)^2

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

In a calculation I end up with the following integral

$$\int_0 ^\infty \frac{p \sin (pr)}{(1+p^2)^2}dp , $$
could someone give me a hint how to evaluate this one?

(This integral comes from the inverse Fourier transform of the function 
$\frac{1}{(1+p^2)^2}$.)

Comment: $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx\iff \int_0^\infty\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(1+x^2)^2}dx=-I'(a)$.

Comment: If you are computing a Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{(1+p^2)^2}$, a much much better way is to use the convolution theorem: the Fourier (or inverse) of $\frac{1}{(1+p^2)}$ is simply an exponential function $e^{-|x|}$ (with some constants in front), you just need to calculate a convolution of this function with itself, which is straight-forward for exponential functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplification thanks to partial integration :

[image]